# Using dart plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I started to learn dart language few weeks ago and really enjoy it, such as nice programming language. As IDE i use dart standard editor and don't like this ide at all, because it is slow.

Then i have hear about, that dart plugin exists for IntelliJ IDEA 13.1. I visit [Dart plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351?pr=phpStorm)
download the newest version 138.35 and try to install it, but it fail.

Then i discover on GitHub [Dart plugin install instructions](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/Dart) and understand only a part of the instructions. Up to section 3.2 was everything fine, i could follow the instructions very well , after section 3.2 i don't understand the instructions anymore, so complicated.

Can somebody explain me in an easy way, how can i install this dart plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub instruction are for those who want to DEVELOP Dart plugin.
To USE it open Settings | Plugins in IntelliJ IDEA, click Install JetBrains Plugin, select Dart and click Install Plugin. 
See some info [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Getting+started+with+Dart).
Feedback is welcome in the [forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity) and [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=#dart).